# Is there any way of connecting an already created ChatBot to Skype for Business?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, skype-for-business

I know Msft has deprecated the addition of bots to Skype for business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Microsoft Teams**, Skype for business is deprecated.

> The Skype for Business Bot Framework channel is in Developer Preview and is not licensed for production usage. **This channel will not be supported after** **6/30/2019**. As part of Microsoft’s intelligent communications vision, we’re building extensible communications capabilities into Teams.